# how to load 2 services (or more) through dependency injection

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

if i have 1 service, i can load my service through dependency injection like:

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  protected $coreService;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct($coreService) {
    $this->coreService = $coreService;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static( $container->get('arm_core.core_service') );
  }
```

but now let say i have 2 services, how i load the service through dependency injection rather than globally?

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  protected $coreService
  protected $mainService;

  //then...?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The key idea here is that if the class you are using implements the ContainerInjectionInterface, you get passed a container object from which you can get any service you like.  Since FormBase implements this, your form will already be able to do this.

Here's some code from D8's [file example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/file_example%21file_example.module/group/file_example/8.x-1.x), from the Example Module, as an example:

```
  /**
   * Constructs a new FileExampleReadWriteForm page.
   *
   * @param StateInterface $state
   *   Storage interface for state data.
   * @param FileSystemInterface $file_system
   *   Interface for common file system operations.
   * @param StreamWrapperManagerInterface $stream_wrapper_manager
   *   Interface to obtain stream wrappers used to manipulate a given file
   *   scheme.
   * @param ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler
   *   Interface to get information about the status of modules and other
   *   extensions.
   * @param RequestStack $request_stack
   *   Access to the current request, including to session objects.
   */
  public function __construct(
    StateInterface $state,
    FileSystemInterface $file_system,
    StreamWrapperManagerInterface $stream_wrapper_manager,
    ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler,
    RequestStack $request_stack
  ) {
    $this->state = $state;
    $this->fileSystem = $file_system;
    $this->moduleHandler = $module_handler;
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
    $this->streamWrapperManager = $stream_wrapper_manager;
    $this->sessionSchemeEnabled = $this->moduleHandler->moduleExists('stream_wrapper_example');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $state = $container->get('state');
    $file_system = $container->get('file_system');
    $module_handler = $container->get('module_handler');
    $request_stack = $container->get('request_stack');
    $stream_wrapper_manager = $container->get('stream_wrapper_manager');
    return new static($state, $file_system, $stream_wrapper_manager, $module_handler, $request_stack);
  }
```

Your create() function calls your constructor, and since you've received a services container, you can ask for whatever and however many services you want.